# How does server distinguish between clients asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How does the server come to know which request is from a new client, and which is a subsequent request from the same client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your configuration.

Two common ways:

1)A session cookie is stored on the user's machine and passed along with each request (session cookie)

2)A guid is included in the url to indicate the user's session

More here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.ASPX